# Limit accepted model attributes in Sailsjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

With Sailsjs, I can create a model and easily add new records:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create
```

I can also add arbitrary attributes to my records:

```
http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=bob
```

How do I restrict or limit what attributes can be set on a model? I thought defining the attributes in the model would do it, but it appears that I can still set any arbitrary attribute I want.

Also, side note, do I need to "relift" sails every time I change a model? Is there a list somewhere of what changes to your framework code require restarting Sails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the property `schema` to `true`, this way only attributes defined in the model's attributes object will be stored.

More info: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html

Comment: Ah just what I was looking for thank you. Easy to miss in the documentation.